# introductory pricing in iTunes connect for users with iOS 11.2 and lower

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have a product (Auto renewal subscription) in iTunes connect which has a introductory price. My question is, do all users get that offer regardless of what iOS version they are using? I did some test in the sandbox and it seems if the device has lower version than iOS 11.2, I'm not getting any message saying that I will get the introductory pricing!

I'm using the new field added to the SKProduct which is only available in iOS 11.2

```
SKProduct.introductoryPrice
```

Anyone have tested it in the production? is that behaviour correct? What will happen if the user is using lower version than iOS 11.2? Will they pay the full price immediately?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

After testing and releasing an app in the app store. Users who have lower than iOS 11.2 they will be charged the subscription price and introductory price will not be available if set any of these in iTunes connect freeTrial, payAsYouGo or payUpFront.

Comment: Hey, does it mean that this [table][1] (from Apple documentation) is wrong? It says that introductory offers are compatible with iOS 10 and later.

The [documentation][2] for the product discount says that it's from iOS 11.2.

My first impression when comparing documentations I was under the assumption that it was available to users from iOS 10 but developers should work around the fact that they don't know the discounted price 

  [1]: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/subscriptions/#offer-types
  [2]: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skproductdiscount